# Run a database query or ftp action based on a mail received

Tags: mysql, email, parsing

I'm looking for a way to receive E-Mails and use data from the email itself.
For example, if a mail with a line "https://xxx/images/jefoef.jpg" is received I need to have a script executing a query to a mysql db.

Basically I just need an idea how I could fetch mails and use "data" from it, so I can go ahead and use the a parameter (for example $1 == jefoef.jpg) and run the mysql query with $1 - but I have no idea how to actually "extract" the data from the mail and run a script with it.

Does anyone have an idea?

Background: the idea is to act "automatically" on CSAM reports and remove flagged / reported images from the server. Either via a mysql query or a direct sftp remove from the server.

Comment: A bunch of the big email providers have ways of setting up inbound mail processing; for example, Amazon SES: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-receive-and-process-incoming-email-with-amazon-ses/ (new emails trigger a SNS notification, which you can pass to any system of your choosing)

Comment: zapier.com may have an automation for this.

Comment: Zapier does the job correct but we can't afford $20 (since the mysql app is premium..) =(